# The OpenCV DNN face detection module can not work with Caffe C++ library

Tags: opencv, caffe, face

I download the caffe source code from Github and compile it as C++ static library, and I test the OpenCV face detection Caffe model with the static library, but the lib report below error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR D:\ThirdPartyLibrary\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:296] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 984:14: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "norm_param".
F0328 02:08:05.225075 24332 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: D:/DATA/PreTrainedModel/cv_facedet/deploy.prototxt
```

is it means that `norm_param` field is implement only by OpenCV, not a standard Caffe field?

Answer (score 1):

`norm_param` is an argument of Normalization layer from [SSD Caffe framework](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd): https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/8a65ae316b34e7c8fdefa6e18bf08a23b78caa0e/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L523

Origin repo: https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd

There is no SSD object detection networks in the [origin Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe).

Comment: OK,so can I run the OpenCV face detection network on the SSD Caffe framework?

Comment: Caffe is not well supported library these days. You may face compilation issues. May I ask you why you wanted to run this model through Caffe but not through OpenCV?

Comment: Because caffe can be accelerated by nvidia cuda,but opencv's dnn module could not be,it only be accelerated by intel's GPU through OpenVINO SDK,but Intel GPU's power is less than nv gpu,so I prefer Caffe;

Comment: Got it. So try this fork. The model has been trained there. Read more in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/face_detector/how_to_train_face_detector.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it has different name in Caffe: `normalize_bbox_param`. See [this discussion](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/935#issuecomment-274683051).

Comment: Hi,Dmytro: 
  
    Thanks your reply, I replace the "norm_param" to "normalize_bbox_param",but caffe lib report "normalize_bbox_param" is unknown too